# SSL Compression Zlib different length

Tags: apache, security, ssl, https, openssl

I am trying to use SSL compression in Chrome to recreate CRIME attack. However I don't understand how it is compressing the data. The length remains same even if I change some inputs. Moreover I am using zlib in python to compress the same data, but I get different length. Can anyone point out why this might be the case?

Comment: "*The length remains same even if I change some inputs.*" What does this mean exactly. Inputs to what? What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I am changing the URL parameters. However the length of SSL record remains same. I expect that if I have URL value same as COOKIE value it will change the length of record, as compression will take place

Comment: What sizes are you using? Maybe they're just not large enough.

Comment: I am using more than 1000 bytes of random padding and than my COOKIENAME=GUESS but whatever guess I try or even change the cookie name, the length remains same.

Comment: Also if I input the same plain text in python, it gives different compression length that one shown in wireshark for SSL records

Comment: How much is the uncompressed length changing?

Comment: Well, SSL has to pad records to prevent attacks based on knowing the length.

Comment: I tried changing uncompressed length is more than 100. Can you tell what exact zlib settings chrome use and how can I simulate compression in python. I am trying to recreate CRIME attack